# Could not start a new session.Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I believe that it is a version issue however not sure which version is not supporting which version.

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Build info:

- version: '4.8.1'
- revision: '8ebccac989'

System info:

- os.name: 'Mac OS X'
- os.arch: 'x86_64'
- os.version: '12.5.1'
- java.version: '1.8.0_361'

I have tried different version.
I have changed java version 8.0 before it was latest version.
I have changed dependencies in POM.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled eclips.
checked with different browsers.

Comment: Update the question with the entire error stacktrace and the version information of Selenium, Browser and Browser Drivers.